# QBS build system: Complex artifact transformation

Tags: qbs

How would be possible to:

1. Compile a .c file resulting an .o object file;
2. Apply a command like xxd (hex dump) over the generated object file resulting a .h header file;
3. Use that generated header in a C/C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the circularity can be broken by having the object file as the target artifact of a dedicated project, e.g. something like this (sketch, untested):

```
Project {
    Product {
        name: "dep"
        type: "obj"
        Depends { name: "cpp" }
        files: "myfile.c"
    }
    Product {
        Depends { name: "dep" }
        Depends { name: "cpp" }
        cpp.includePaths: product.buildDirectory // So the generated header will be found
        Rule {
            inputsFromDependencies: "obj"
            Artifact { filePath: "theHeader.h"; fileTags: "hpp" }
            prepare: {
                var cmd = new Command("xxd", [input.filePath, output.filePath]);
                cmd.description = "generating " + output.fileName;
                return cmd;
            } 
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: That sequence can be performed by a CMake project. As I understand the circular dependency is caused by the file path of generated header. That dependency might be avoided using a symlink. How the project would look like only for points 1. and 2.?